# jQuery for setting value of an input type with selected radio value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Able to select the value of the selected radio button but unable to pass it to the required place which is the value of an input type (id = redirect).

```
<label>Transaction Mode</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="bank" value="Bank" 
onclick="myFunction()"> Direct Bank Transfer 
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="online" value="Online" 
onclick="myFunction()"> Credit Card / Paypal 
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cheque" value="Cheque" 
onclick="myFunction()"> Cheque / Pay Order 
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cash" value="Cash" 
onclick="myFunction()"> Cash

<input type=hidden name="redirect" id="redirect" value="">
<script>
 function myFunction() {
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
        var x = $("input[name='mode']:checked").val();
        if($(x).val == "Bank"){
        alert("bank.php");
        }
        });
        }); 
        } 
</script>
```

The alert is not showing the selected radio value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplyify the logic and simply append .php to the value of the radio button that is clicked (which by definition means that is checked). This will give you the desired page url to go to for that checked radio input.

I am also passing that redirectLocation to the value of your hidden input which I assume is the purpose of this.

In the name of better code - ou should be having the text of each radio button in a label element which is either wrapping the radio input or referring to it with the for="id" attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
     var redirectLocation = $(this).val().toLowerCase() + '.php';
     $('#redirect').val(redirectLocation);
     alert(redirectLocation);
   }); 
   
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Transaction Mode</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="bank" value="Bank"> Direct Bank Transfer 
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="online" value="Online"> Credit Card / Paypal 
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cheque" value="Cheque"> Cheque / Pay Order 
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cash" value="Cash"> Cash

<input type=hidden name="redirect" id="redirect" value="">
```

Comment: You nailed it! Simple and perfect. Since there are other radio buttons in the code I have changed $(this) to $("input[name='mode']:checked"). Is this ok or there is a simpler way than this. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Consider making the following changes to your code:

- avoid the use of inline event bindings (ie `onclick="myFunction()"`) in your HTML. Instead delegate event binding to JQuery (ie as you've done with the `.click()` handler.
- you'll typically want to avoid wrapping the `.ready()` handler in a function called by a user event. The `.ready()` handler is invoked [when the DOM of the page can be safely interacted with](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) - wrapping the `.ready()` handler with a user triggered function (ie `myFunction()`) convolutes the intended trigger point of this handler.

The suggested changes in code would look like this:

```js
/* Don't enclose this in another function - it is run once page is ready */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked') && 
        $(this).val() === 'Bank') {

      /* If the clicked radio is checked and the value matches 'Bank'
         show alert() */
 
      alert("bank.php");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Transaction Mode</label>
<br>
<!-- remove onclick event bindings -->
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="bank" value="Bank"> Direct Bank Transfer
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="online" value="Online"> Credit Card / Paypal
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cheque" value="Cheque"> Cheque / Pay Order
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cash" value="Cash"> Cash


<input type=hidden name="redirect" id="redirect" value="">
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That worked. Can you please explain why to avoid inline event bindings? I am running some other functions too with it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @haroon glad to hear this helped. Sure - although what you currently have isn't necessarily wrong, the `$.ready()` inside of your `myFunction()` adds complexity that can be avoided by what I've shown above. Additionally, the intent of `$.ready(fn)` is to call `fn` once the page is "ready to be interacted with by jquery" - by running `$.ready()` at a later time, (ie after user interaction) is a bit confusing - it's almost to suggest that the page won't be ready by the time the user is interacting with the page.

Comment: I already did the first time but it says that my vote is recorded but not published due to less than 15 reputations

Answer (score 0):

You already have the value (as a string) in your `x` variable when you do

```
var x = $("input[name='mode']:checked").val();
```

So, just test if that is `=== 'Bank'`:

```js
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
  var x = $("input[name='mode']:checked").val();
  if (x === "Bank") {
    console.log("bank.php");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Transaction Mode</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="bank" value="Bank"> Direct Bank Transfer
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="online" value="Online"> Credit Card / Paypal
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cheque" value="Cheque"> Cheque / Pay Order
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cash" value="Cash"> Cash


<input type=hidden name="redirect" id="redirect" value="">
```

Feel free to use standard DOM methods, there's no need for a big library like jQuery for something this trivial:

```js
document.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.name === 'mode') {
    return;
  }
  const val = target.value;
  if (val === 'Bank') {
    console.log("bank.php");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Transaction Mode</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="bank" value="Bank"> Direct Bank Transfer
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="online" value="Online"> Credit Card / Paypal
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cheque" value="Cheque"> Cheque / Pay Order
<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="cash" value="Cash"> Cash


<input type=hidden name="redirect" id="redirect" value="">
```

Comment: Any reason for obliteratingly obfuscating `Event`? It's certainly not going to be treeshaked anyways ;) You'd even save some bytes by simply doing `e =>` or the humanly preferred `evt =>`

Comment: Everyone already knows that the argument to the `addEventListener` callback is the event, right? I don't like defining an entire object in a scope if I'm only going to use one property of the object, immediate destructuring means less baggage for the remaining scope of the callback IMO. (though I suppose it doesn't matter so much for something so short)